# Is there a way to read Chrome browser alerts in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, element

Currently developing a checkout script and on the final stage a Chrome alert appears within the Webdriver like here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPyT4.png
I need to be able to read what that message says to determine if the payment was successful, if so I need to be able to terminate all other instances of script I plan to run from a batch file, and print that payment was successful. Or if payment decline or gateway is rejected as shown above, I need to be able to print that it was declined or that there was a gateway rejection. 
Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try 
`driver.switchTo().alert()`
One you have switched, something like 
`driver.getPageSource()` should work

Comment: Yes but I need to be able to 'read' the text from the alert to determine what will happen after that. For example if payment is declined, to print it to the user. Or if successful to terminate all other 'tasks'. Do you have an example of how I would be able to write a code to identify what the alert said inside of it?